# Android Change Text Color of Spinner (displayed text - not items in spinner)

Tags: android, android-layout, android-spinner

Except for one screen, the `Spinner` needs to have 'black' text. The one screen requires `Spinner` to have 'White' color (both displayed text for the selected item and spinner items).

Here is the image for better clarity. [image: top image is how it appears in black color and the bottom is the spinner items image with white text color]

I'm able to get 'White' color for spinner items but not the selected displayed text. Again, I don't want to globally change the styling - just this one screen. Is this possible?

Comment: have you created custom adapter for it?

Comment: you can define a style for spinner and set textColor as item property.

Comment: If You are using custom adapter than in getView() method check whether current item is selected or not and change the text color accordingly using setText(Html.fromHtml("<font color=\"#FFFFFF/#000000\">" + text + "</font>")) of textview

Comment: @user3676184 no, I'm not using a custom adapter.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) { 
    int index = adapterView.getSelectedItemPosition();
    ((TextView) spinner.getSelectedView()).setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.white));
}
```

Comment: This works but there is a short delay of few milli-seconds duration before which the color changes to 'white'. Is there a better way?

Comment: instead of `getResources().getColor(xxx)` try `setTextColor(Color.white)`

Comment: Also we can use setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#ffffff")); for white color and setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#000000")); for black color

Answer (score 0):

When you creating Spinner you have to provide it with adapter. If you were using standart implementation from android developers:

```
 Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);
// Create an ArrayAdapter using the string array and a default spinner layout
ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,
        R.array.planets_array, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
```

Than what you can do is to create your own layout that for representing selected item text that is provided as and put it inside adapter and there you can provide 'textColor' atribute, something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      android:id="@android:id/text1"
      style="?android:attr/spinnerItemStyle"
      android:singleLine="true"
      android:textColor="@color/primary_blue"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:ellipsize="marquee"
      android:textAlignment="inherit"/>
```

If you are using `ArrayAdapter.createFromResource()` don't forget to have TextView with `android:id="@android:id/text1"` so this adapter will be able to bind data to your layout.